# Kolab on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd

I want to install [Kolab](http://kolab.org) on FreeBSD 10. It seems there are no precompiled packages available, so I have to compile from source.

On Kolab's Git server the latest Kolab server available is version 2.3.4 (3 years old) and Kolab is now at version 3.4.
Many other repositories are available, though.

My first question is: Which of the available repositories (if any) is needed to compile a Kolab server?

To see if I could get any hints I cloned the [kolabs-doc](http://git.kolab.org/kolab-docs) repository. 
Unfortunately, when trying run the included MakeFiles I get errors:

```
make[1]: publican: No such file or directory
```

even though there are plenty of files named `publican.cfg` in the subdirectories.

Am I missing something in the compilation?

Answer (score 0):

Been a bit since I've used FreeBSD, but if memory serves you should be able to put in the Linux compatibility port and run it from that.

A more fun way, would be to install Kolab onto Linux compatibility and just use it as a reference. When installing Kolab, get a list of all packages it wants to install. Then grab the diff new files in your `/etc` and `/var` and such. Go through with the install and get your basic setup.

Kolab lists it's technologies, off the top of my head it's postfix, dovecot, openldap, apache2, spamassasin, mysql. Without checking I'm sure this is all available on FreeBSD.

After installing the packages/ports needed, you should be able to copy and paste configurations (`/etc` maybe alter some directory locations as needed), sql databases (`/var`), ldap databases (`/var` again), and web directories (`/srv` or `/var/www` depending on which linux compat you picked) right into your freebsd environment. After all most of the magic of Kolab is schema and php.

Good luck in your venture! Let us know if you get it working :)

Comment: I know this is against the comment policy, but I don't want to be rude by not reacting. First, thanks for your answer! Second, I eventually settled for another solution (and had forgotten about this question).

Answer (score 0):

`publican`has been removed from ports as [unstaged](http://www.freshports.org/textproc/publican/)

So you need to compile it from source as well.

Answer (score -3):

Sorry to tell you that BUT there's NO groupware solution for FreeBSD. FreeBSD does NOT care about groupware like kolab 3, sogo (incl. openchange) and many other groupware solutions (incl. an outlook connector). It's sad but a lot of IT persons had to switch over to linux because of missing groupware. For some reasons they did not realize that a server OS without groupware is in most cases dispensable. My suggestion: Delete FreeBSD and use LINUX instead!

rgds
Rohman

Comment: There is a [SOGo port](https://freshports.org/www/sogo/) and also some [other groupware](https://freshports.org/search.php?stype=shortdescription&query=groupware)

Comment: Kolab is a php thing, there is no reason to not use php anywhere as you want.